# jQuery Mobile: How do you write multiple horizontal radio groups into one fieldset with headings/legends?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, fieldset

Using jQuery Mobile and Horizontal radio field sets as show at:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/checkboxradio-radio/#Horizontalgroup

What's the proper way to write two (or many) different radio groups into a single fieldset (if possible). Writing multiple horizontal radio groups into a single fieldset seems strange to me. I'm not sure if I'm using all the elements properly.

```
<div data-role="page" id="test">
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">

            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-theme="a" data-type="horizontal">

                <legend>FieldSet Name:</legend>

                <div class="ui-field-contain">
                    <legend>Question 1:</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1-no" value="1">
                    <label for="radio-choice-1-no">No</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1-yes" value="2">
                    <label for="radio-choice-1-yes">Yes</label>
                </div>

                <div class="ui-field-contain">
                    <legend>Question 2:</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-2-no" value="1">
                    <label for="radio-choice-2-no">No</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-2-yes" value="2">
                    <label for="radio-choice-2-yes">Yes</label>
                </div>

            </fieldset>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Va2pv/ wrap each control group and legend in `ui-field-contain`.

Comment: Yes, it is similar to that jsfiddle. Except, I'm trying to show both the Question Labels "Question 1:" and "Question 2:" within a grouping "Fieldset" with another legend.

Comment: This jsfiddle seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/J95fe/  Now I've just got to translate it into my dynamically built code. I seem to have some data-role differences. My CSS may also be causing problems.